# Twitter json object undefined (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, search, twitter, undefined

Hi I'm just trying to do some simple AJAX stuff by retrieving search results from Twitter. It is bringing back the objects but I can't seem to drill down to the object itself and get the info (such as text).

If I console.log(tweet), it lists all the objects, but the code below just says "undefined". I'm sure I'm missing something easy.

I've read loads of questions/answers on here but none seem to do it. I see many have used the .getJSON() method, but using .ajax() should be ok I would have thought?

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=twitter&rpp=5',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(i,tweet){
                console.log(tweet.text);
                //$('#twitter ul').append('<li><a href="' + item.text + '">' + item.from_user_id + '</a></li>');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `data.results`

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=twitter&rpp=5',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.results, function(i,tweet){
            alert(tweet.text);
            //$('#twitter ul').append('<li><a href="' + item.text + '">' + item.from_user_id + '</a></li>');
        });
    }
});
```

You can find a working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TUuTz/).

Updated:

I think you are new to javascript and json data format.

The data returned by the request `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=twitter&rpp=5` is in [json](http://www.json.org/js.html) format. The response for the request contains a key value pair. If you copy paste the request url in your browser you can see the result of the query.

It starts with {results: [....]}, it means that the json object contains an array of items which can be accessed used the key `results`.

Each item in the results array contains the following values

```
{
    "from_user_id_str":"",
    "profile_image_url":"",
    "created_at":"",
    "from_user":"",
    "id_str":"",
    "metadata":{"result_type":"recent"},
    "to_user_id":null,
    "text":"",
    "id":,
    "from_user_id": 0,
    "geo":null,
    "iso_language_code":"en",
    "to_user_id_str":null,
    "source":""
}
```

each of these key/values can be accessed with the the `$.each(function(i, tweet){ .... })` using `tweet.<key name>`. Ex: tweet.from_user_id_str, tweet.text, tweet.source etc...

Comment: Great! Thanks for that. I hadn't heard of data.results. Fogive the noob but are there any other data.X methods?

When getting my delicious bookmarks (also json), I didn't need data.results. 'data' worked fine.